# Tutle example How to think like a Computer Scientist Turtle Terminator error

Tags: python, error-handling, python-turtle

I am a relative beginner to programming and was studying using how to think like a computer scientist. When completing one of the examples, I consistently run into the error of turtle.Terminator.

```
import time

def show_poly():
    try:
        import turtle
        win = turtle.Screen() # Grab/create a resource e.g. a window
        tess = turtle.Turtle()
    
        # This dialog could be cancelled 
        # or the conver to int might fail, or n might be zero.
    
        n = int(input("How many sides do you want in your polygon?"))
        angle = 360 / n
    
        for i in range(n): # Draw the polygon
            tess.forward(10)
            tess.left(angle)
        time.sleep(3)
    finally:
        win.bye() # Close the turtle's window

show_poly()
show_poly()
show_poly()
```

I receive this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rohanbansal/mu_code/turtlefinally.py", line 
24, in <module>
    show_poly()
  File "/Users/rohanbansal/mu_code/turtlefinally.py", line 8, in show_poly
    tess = turtle.Turtle()
      File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 3813, in __init__
RawTurtle.__init__(self, Turtle._screen,
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2557, in __init__
self._update()
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2660, in _update
self._update_data()
  File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 2646, in _update_data
self.screen._incrementudc()
   File "/Applications/Mu Editor.app/Contents/Resources/Python/lib/python3.8/turtle.py", line 1292, in _incrementudc
raise Terminator
turtle.Terminator
```

When trying to deal with issue/ de-bugging, I found that the error was with the creation of the next turtle (ie. After the first show_poly() occurs, the next time turtle.Turtle occurs, it leads to a turtle.Terminator error).

I included the import turtle into the definition of show_poly, as I found on stack overflow that this was a potential solution. Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

from the [turtle doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html):

> The function Screen() returns a singleton object of a TurtleScreen
> subclass.

you won't be able to launch three `Screen`s in one script. why don't you just clean/reset the screen?

Comment: Thank you, that is a much simpler to deal with

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this code:

```
finally:
        win.bye() # Close the turtle's window
```

The `finally` clause is *always* executed, so it even closes down the turtle window system on success.  Once you close down the turtle's window system in *standalone* turtle, you can't restart it.  If you try to, you get that `Terminator` error.

Let's rework the program a bit, primarily recasting the `finally` as an `except` which will shut the program down cleanly on bad input.  Probably not exactly what was intended, nor a perfectly correct program (e.g. bare `except`) but should show the power of a `try` clause:

```
import time
from turtle import Screen, getturtle

def show_poly():
    try:
        screen = Screen()  # Grab/create a resource e.g. a window
        screen.clear()

        turtle = getturtle()

        # This dialog could be cancelled
        # or the conversion to int might fail, or n might be zero.

        n = int(input("How many sides do you want in your polygon? "))
        angle = 360 / n

        for _ in range(n):  # Draw the polygon
            turtle.forward(10)
            turtle.left(angle)

        time.sleep(3)
    except:
        screen.bye()  # Close the turtle's window
        exit()

show_poly()
show_poly()
show_poly()
```

I switched from `Turtle()` to `getturtle()` as you're basically piling up dead turtles (they aren't garbage collected) so instead, we're just reusing the default turtle singleton.

Comment: Thank you so much that is really helpful